# FB.login() not asking for given permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook

The login is working, but it only asks for basic permissions and no alert is triggering when canceling or finishing the dialog.

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXX', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : 'XXX', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
      frictionlessRequests: true,
      oauth: true
    });

     FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         alert("ok");
       } else {
        alert("canceled");
       }
     }, {scope:'publish_actions,publish_stream'});

  };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using fb:login-button? If so, have you tried adding the permissions there instead of in FB.login()? So it would look something like:

```
<fb:login-button scope="publish_actions,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as the right answer. This solved my problem. The method `FB.Login` does not send the `scope` parameter when using the `fb:login-button`. It seems a facebook library bug.

Comment: This took soooo long to find! Has anyone reported this to facebook as a bug yet? When using `XFBML`, `{scope:''}` is ignored completely.

Answer (score 3):

## Important: If your Facebook application is public then submit the permission you wanted for a review to Facebook if you have not done this. Check your developer dashboard. If you are in development, do not make your app public and add users for testing through Facebook dashboard.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just starting out. I didn't understand why queries with additional permissions worked via Graph API Explorer, but not in my app. Your answer got me unstuck. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you will use OG Actions, if not, you should read this about the publish_actions / publish_stream: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/

For your problem about alerts, try to remove the oauth var.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. `FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope:'publish_actions'});` is also not working..

Comment: It works when I put it directly on the onlick event: `onclick="FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope:'publish_actions'});"`

Comment: I see, anyway it's not a good idea to fire the FB.login() automatically, and on every pages. Here is a little example which should help you: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/15720747/2212966