# Javascript not requesting permissions from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

and nor giving error when trying to access stuff that is out side of current permissions but just returning user id...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({appId:'12345myIdHere', status:true, cookie:true, xfbml:true});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

 if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
      console.log(response);
   } else { testLogin(); }});};

function testLogin() { FB.login({scope: 'user_status'}); }

function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) { console.log(response); });
    FB.api('/me?fields=statuses', function(response) { console.log(response); });
}
```

Response from permission show that only basic permissions have been given and in my app settings as a user it also show that app uses no extra permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it..it's the bug in Facebook api...if xfbml is set to true the scope object is completely ignored. So set permissions on login button or use your own login button and change xfbml to false.

[FB.login() not asking for given permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730941/fb-login-not-asking-for-given-permissions)